# JavaScript test (mocha) code organization

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I wrote a JavaScript test using Mocha. In my project I have folder named "helpers" with export modules like `back_to_main_menu`, `go_Offline`, `go_Online`, etc. I also have another folder where we can find files with single test.

Every file starts with a lot of lines which look like

```
const {someFunction} = require(‘../helpers/someFunction’)
```

I want to ask you how to organize it better and avoid this many lines of code in every test file. I don't want to put all the helper functions in one file, because I want to keep quick overview of the names of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider combining your test files into 1 test file, as this will reduce the imports. If this makes it too difficult to visualize your tests, mocha has a solution for this.

Nest your describe/it statements
`describe('a big section of code'){
  it.('should do a thing'){
    it.('should do a sub task of the thing'){`